# add subscript when expression already has a subscript

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

A subscript to a subscript can be accomplished by `a_{b_c}` in a way that the `c` is really subscript to `b`, and both together subscript to `a`. However, `{a_b}_c` behaves differently (either `b` and `c` appear at the same height, or `c` is only slightly lower).

My problem is that I'm generating LaTeX code from a script language, and I get an expression like `{a_b}` (in parentheses) and a subscript `c`, and I can't take the expression apart to form `a_{b_c}`. Is there a way to leave the expression `{a_b}` unchanged and produce the same behavior as `a_{b_c}` or to lower subscript `c` somehow?

Edit: Here's the test script including the two suggestions by David Carlisle:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  a_{b_c} {a_b}_c a_b\vphantom{a}_c a_b{}_c
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: result]

Comment: To me it sounds as if the real solution is to use parentheses, `(a_b)_c`.

Answer (score 4):

`{a_b}_c` would seem to be the natural result although a couple of alternatives to get closer to `a_{b_c}` layout

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\[
a_{b_c}
+
a_b\vphantom{a_b}_{\scriptscriptstyle c}
+
a_b{}_{_{c}}
\]

\end{document}
```

The vphantom will handle cases where the terms are not just `a` and `b` and have larger depth, but require you to have access to the preceding term to duplicate it, the last form just uses empty math atoms and handles most "normal" cases.

Comment: Hmm, for me that has exactly the opposite effect in both cases: the small vertical offset completely disappears.

Comment: It does ;-), please see the edit in my question.

Comment: oh sorry I misread, I thought you wanted same result as `a_{bc}`   so you want `a_b\vphantom{a_b}_{\scriptscriptsyle c}`  if you really want to do this

Comment: Thanks, but `a_b\vphantom{a_b}_c` doesn't work either; `b` and `c` have the same height.

Comment: This seems to work, but the horizontal space is too small (is there another negative math space?): `{{a_b}_{\!}}_c`.

Comment: @Ralf no they do not have the same height the c is lower, but anyway I updated the answer with versions that I think you will prefer.

Comment: @Ralf that makes a scriptsize c, but you seemed to indicate you wanted it to look like `a_{b_c}` which has a scriptscript size ie 5pt rather than 7pt. `\!` is -3mu you can use whatever space you want (but beware the space in `b_c` is specified by the font and will depend on the characters used, you can not reproduce that without a lot of effort.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Unicode math Latin-Modern-Math font, then `${a_b}_c$` gives result with visible lowering of c. Compare two math fonts: the source file

```
Computer Modern, classic math: ${a_b}_c$

\fontfam[lm]

Latin Modern Unicode math: ${a_b}_c$

\bye
```

processed by OpTeX gives the result:

[image: asubb]

Comment: This works with `\fontfam[newcm]` and `\fontfam[ebgaramond]`, too.